# RTL8188CUS AP and Client mode simultaneously with hostapd in Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to figure out how to set up my RTL8188CUS Wifi dongle to run in both AP and Client mode at the same time.

How can I do this in Linux?

I have `hostapd` running fine and I remember reading about AP+Client mode somewhere a while ago for the RTL8188, but I can't remember where.

**Additional info**

I'm on Debian 4.7.2-5 for ARM.
Linux kernel 3.4.90+.

I found the following threads that might be of use and (I think) relevant:

**Link 1**: [How do I use a single wireless adapter for both an access point and client on raspberry pi?](https://superuser.com/questions/612155/how-do-i-use-a-single-wireless-adapter-for-both-an-access-point-and-client-on-ra)
**Link 2**: [Creating WiFi Access point on a single interface in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/615664/creating-wifi-access-point-on-a-single-interface-in-linux)

I tried the first first link, no success.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get `iw list` to work on Debain 8 Jessie x64.

It outputs the following:

> ```
> software interface modes (can always be added):
>
>     * AP/VLAN
>     * monitor
>
> interface combinations are not supported
> ```

However according to Realteks release notes of their latest drivers
they state that the RTL8188CUS supports concurrent modes such as `STA+AP` as of version `4.0.0_5967.20121201`

Doesn't this contradict what `iw list` states?

If not, how would an `STA+AP` mode be achieved?

**UPDATE**
I figured it out. Please see my answer for more info.

Comment: Adding details of the distribution and version would probably help.

Comment: @jcaron good idea. I updated.

Comment: You ought to investigate why the command 'iw dev wlan0 del' does not work, it is a standard command in Debian, and the arm architecture does have the **iw** package.  You should have it already installed, by default that is.

Comment: dang. how do I figure that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem after a couple of weeks of research.

Simple answer is;

The command `iw` does not find any indications of mixed modes on RTL chips.
The reason being that the RTL drivers by default do not support mixed modes.

Realtek call this `Concurrent modes`, and the RTL drivers are by default compiled with the concurrent mode-related code commented out.

In order to compile the drivers **with** concurrent mode activated you need to simply uncomment 3 lines of code in their source code.

Concurrent modes supported are `STA+STA, STA+AP, STA+P2P`.

You can find my full back-story and full guide on how to compile the drivers and the RTL compatible `HOSTAPD` version on this link:

http://randomstuffidosometimes.blogspot.se/2016/03/rtl8192cu-and-rtl8188cus-in-station-and.html

Comment: Thanks for the great research you did here. Now I'm trying to find a chip that does STA+AP simultaneous on different channels, possibly but not necessarily different bands.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on network cards. I do not own an RTL8188, so i cannot tell you off-hand, but I can show you how to find out.

You must issue the command

```
 iw list
```

and, among its abundant output, you will find something like:

```
Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
             * AP
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
    software interface modes (can always be added):
             * AP/VLAN
             * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
             * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1,
               total <= 2, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match
             * #{ managed } <= 2,
               total <= 2, #channels <= 1
```

`AP` mode is the Access Point mode, `managed` is the usual client mode, and this is for my card.

You must check that both `AP` and `managed` appear among the supported modes, then you must check the valid interface combinations: in my case, the first allowed combination is clearly that of a (simultaneous) AP and managed mode (but no more than one each), **provided** the same channel is used. It might be different in your case.

In order to make this work, you must have two distinct virtual interfaces on the same NIC. You do it as follows:

```
service network-manager stop
iw dev wlan0 del
iw phy phy0 interface add new0 type station
service network-manager start
iw phy phy0 interface add new1 type __ap
hostapd -B /etc/hostapd.conf
```

First I stop the network manager, which has its own way of messing everything up, then I rename `new0` the virtual interface on the physical interface called `phy0` (adapt it to your case if yours is not called `phy0`, you obtain the name from the output of `iw list`), restart the network manager so that I can connect the virtual interface `new0` to whichever AP I have near me.

Now I can add a new interface of type `AP` on the same hardware (please notice the *double underscore* preceding `ap` in the command), lastly I start `hostpad`.

The configuration of `hostapd` and of routing/DNS/DHCP depends on your specific needs, and cannot be established *a priori*.

Comment: Thanks, but on the first command I get an error saying that the service `network-manager` does not exist. What should I do? I run no graphical software, my device is pure non-gui.

Comment: @vaid If you do not have a network-manager, that's no problem, just forget about it. You will have to learn how to connet via wifi from the CLI, that's all.

Comment: Im sorry, you might have misunderstood me as I might have not been clear enough. I can connect to a network of my choice or run in AP mode as I wish, I know how to do that. I would like to figure out how to do both at the same time. Or am I misunderstanding you now?

Comment: It's weird `iw list`gives me no output, but `iwlist`does? Anyways `iwlist` gives me the following output:

Comment: [interface] scanning [essid NNN] [last]
              [interface] frequency 
              [interface] channel 
              [interface] bitrate 
              [interface] rate 
              [interface] encryption 
              [interface] keys 
              [interface] power 
              [interface] txpower 
              [interface] retry 
              [interface] ap 
              [interface] accesspoints

Comment: [interface] peers 
              [interface] event 
              [interface] auth 
              [interface] wpakeys 
              [interface] genie 
              [interface] modulation

Comment: Btw, I can't run any of the commands you provided. For example `iw dev wlan0 del` gives me the error `command failed: No such device (-19)`. But `wlan0` does exist. What should I do?

Comment: @vaid What is the output of *iwconfig*? If that fails, of *ifconfig*? If that fails, of *ip link show*?

Comment: please see the edit in my question. I added the output there since the text won't be properly formatted in a comment.

Comment: I have managed to figure out why `iw list` doesn't work, as you may have noticed on the other question. please read my edited question for more information.

Comment: I have now also figured out how to put an `RTL8188CUS` and `RTL8192CU` in `STA+AP` mode. I'll answer my own question once I've documented a step-by-step guide.