# "iw" and some of its commands do not return any output

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, debian-wheezy, hostapd

I've been trying to set up my ARM based computer so that it becomes
a hotspot and a client at the same time.

However all of the information I've found about such functionality mention
the `iw` command which seems to be crucial for me to solve the problem I'm having.

It does not seem to work properly for me.

When I type `iw wlan0 info` I get the error message `command failed: No such device (-19)`.

Why is this happening?

I'm on Debian Wheezy.

**EDIT:** I have a fully functional WiFi dongle connected to the ARM computer. The WiFi dongle is the only connection to my network.

The Wifi dongle is based on `RTL8188CUS`.

**IMPORTANT**

I managed to get it to work briefly by doing the following:

Add `contrib non-free` to the first two sources in /etc/apt/sources.list

Run `apt-get update`
Run `apt-get upgrade`

Run `apt-get install firmware-realtek`

Connect wifi dongle

Run `iw list`, it works now.

**Kind of off topic, but related to why I need IW to work, and I'll get back to IW after my explanation**

The wifi dongle I have uses an `RTL8188CUS` chip, and according to RealTek's
release notes this chip should support mixed modes as of version `4.0.0_5967.2021201`.

By mixed modes I mean `Station+Station`, `Station+AP`, `Station+P2P`.

*Note: The mode "Station" is also refered to as "Managed"*

I've been trying to figure out how to make this chip use the Station+AP for months now, however, old drivers have been installed on every system I've used and set up, until I found this (which I'm trying now): https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

I've found some more resources which I'll try later.

NOW, back to `IW`;

`IW` seems to stop working when the wrong drivers are used.

Even though I use the wrong drivers, I still manage to connect the Wifi dongle
to any network, but `IW` no longer recognizes the device.

`IWCONFIG` works fine, `IFCONFIG` works fine.

So I believe that the wrong drivers will cause commands such as `iw dev` to stop working.

Additional information: the module `8192cu` is never loaded when following the installation steps in the GITHUB above.

I know, they are not for the same driver, but they should still work for `8188cu` according to RealTek.

Comment: I cannot find any reference to a kernel 3.4.90 in debian wheezy, arm architecture or not. It seems like you are using a custom kernel. I am unable  to help you further, you will have to find either a newer kernel or the appropriate headers wherever you downloaded the custom kernel. Sorry,  this is the end of the line of what I can do.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes, that is correct, I believe it's a custom kernel. One last question: how could compile my own up-to-date kernel?

Comment: Why do you want to compile it yourself? Isn't it better to install a mainline kernel?

Comment: How can I do that? The CPU is an Allwinner A10, and the debian image I installed was made specifically for this type of CPU and dev board I'm using. Not many people have managed to get Debian to work on this device. What I have right now is the only thing that seems to work. I think this fits in a different discussion. Would you be interested in talking to me and teach me one or two things about linux and the kernel and how I could install a mainline kernel?

Comment: Ignore my question, I've updated my original post.

Comment: In case anyone else ends up here .. it looks like the iw command needs the driver to implement the 'cfg80211' interface, and not all of them do.

Answer (score 1):

Install the `iw` package,

```
 apt-get install iw
```

then you will have the `iw` command.

***EDIT:***

it is pretty obvious at this moment that you have a bug somewhere. You have the following alternatives:

1. Since you have a very old kernel, 3.4.90 ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1035755/rtl8188-ap-and-client-mode-simultaneously-with-hostapd-in-linux)), you may wish to dramatically update your kernel. There are guides to do this all over Google.
2. you may try to recompile the device driver, in the hope that the bug is there, not in the old version of `iw` you run. You do this as follows: downloads Linux backports [from here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz), go to the directory where you downloaded the above file, and give these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential firmware-realtek
   tar xvfz backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
   cd backports-4.4.2-1/
   make defconfig-rtlwifi
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Reboot, try your `iw` commands again. If this fails, I can only suggest updating your old kernel: 3.4 was released [in May 2012](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.4).

Comment: `iwconfig` works fine. It shows my WiFi device as expected.

Comment: btw, you've been trying to help me with something related to this before @MariusMatutiae. And I still haven't solved it.

Comment: `iw` is also insatalled. I've reinstalled it as well.

Comment: Yes. I do everything in root.

Comment: I don't have any other wifi adapter, however, when I connect the wifi adapter that I am using in to my x86 linux computer `iw` works fine.

Comment: Sure, can I use a command to figure out the vendor and product code?

Comment: Here's the output of `lsusb`: `Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter`

Comment: Ok, the line `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential firmware-realtek` gives me the error `E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.4.90` and `E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.4.90'`. I've encountered this before, but I don't recall resolving it.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just insane. I can't find ANY information about why `iw <commands>` does not work. It also stopped working on my x86 Linux computer for some reason. I've installed a fresh version of Debian Jessie on VirtualBox and same thing there. It just won't work and it's driving me crazy. Why does it not work?

Comment: Could it be that some service is using the device so that `iw` can't read it? When I write `iw wlan0 link` it says `Not connected`

Comment: Please see my edit in the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `wireless_tools`

Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
aptitude install wireless-tools
```

Restart network services:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

**Update**

You need to add  interfaces with `iw`

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add <name> type <type>
```

For wired connection:

```
iw phy phy0 interface add <name> type <type>
```

There are several modes supported. The modes supported are:

- monitor
- managed [also station]
- wds
- mesh [also mp]
- ibss [also adhoc]

Example:

```
iw phy phy0 interface add moni0 type monitor
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan0 type station
```

Comment: It says that `wireless-tools` is already installed.

Comment: By doing `iw dev wlan0 interface add <name> type <type>` I just get help information which tries to tell me how to use `iw`.

Comment: I think that `iw` doesn't know what physical devices are available somehow.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. That's exactly how I wrote it. I replaced `<name>` with `wlan0` and `<type>` with `managed` because it worked on my other computer which is x86 based.

Comment: Yes, `wpa_supplicant` is also installed.

Comment: the ouput of `rfkill list`

Comment: it says `bash: rfkill: command not found` I guess I have to install it

Comment: I installed it, now when I write `rfkill list` it returns nothing. It just goes straight to bash again.

Comment: please see the edit in my question. btw, I never managed to get rfkill to work